# Mockito ArgumentCaptor Capture Conditional on Matcher

Tags: java, mockito

In mockito we can capture arguments for a method that might be called many times like so:

```
verify(mocked, atLeastOnce())
    .myMethod(myCaptor.capture());
```

Then

```
myCaptor.getAllValues()
```

However then I would need to sift through all the captured values to find the one I am interested in for verification.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
private class IsMySpecialArg extends ArgumentMatcher<Object> {
  public boolean matches(Object other) {
    // Matching condition
  }
}
```

...

```
verify(mocked, atLeastOnce())
        .myMethod(myCaptor.capture(argThat(new IsMySpecialArg()));
```

So that I can simply call `myCaptor.getValue()` and be assured it is referring to the argument I was actually interested in capturing. What is the best way to accomplish this is `mockito`, is it supported, or is there something fundamentally wrong with my testing strategy?

Comment: If you are only interested in getValue() rather than getAllValues() from the ArgumentCaptor why not just drop the ArgumentCaptor completely in favour of using your ArgumentMatcher?

Comment: Oh can the ArgumentMatcher also capture the value it matches? Basically I want to capture the argument then get the captured object and do some further stuff with it, the object has members, like InputStream s which are not easy to express in a matcher

Comment: @qwwqwwq Seems reasonable if you absolutely need to capture it and can't express it in the matcher. Have you tried it out?

Comment: Mark's suggestion is the correct one.  Whatever "further stuff" it is that you're intending to do with the object that you capture - just put it in the matcher.  There should be no need to do two stages of checking - one in the matcher and one after the object is captured.

Answer (score 0):

I use ArgumentMatchers pretty frequently when writing tests. Here's an example of what you can do when verifying the arguments that are passed to your mock objects:

```
private static class ExpectationArgumentMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<String> {

    private final List<String> expectedArguments;

    public ExpectationArgumentMatcher(List<String> expectedArguments) {
        this.expectedArguments = expectedArguments;
    }

    public ExpectationArgumentMatcher() {
        this(new ArrayList<javax.swing.Action>());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        if (argument instanceof String) {
            String actualArgument = (String) argument;
            return expectedArguments.contains(actualArgument);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you're expected arguments could just be a string, or something more sophisticated, but you're basically checking that your mock was called upon with an argument that matches your expected argument(s).